# How to get values of elements of a dynamically added directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to know how can I read the values of elements of a dynamically added directive.

Plunker here: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/he81ccvklc8luZB9

```
var dynamicDirective = angular.module('testapp', []);

dynamicDirective.controller('mycontroller', ['$scope', '$compile', function($scope, $compile) {

      $scope.add = function() {
        angular.element(document.getElementById('container'))
          .append($compile("<textbox></textbox>")($scope));
      }

      $scope.read = function(){
        console.log("Your values");
      }


  }]);

  dynamicDirective.directive('textbox', [function() {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'dynamictextbox.html',
      scope: {

      },
      controller: function($scope) {

      }
    };
  }]);
```

### dynamictextbox.html

```
<div>
  First name: <input type="text"/> <br/>
  Last name: <input type="text"/> <br/>
  Age: <input type="text"/> <br/>
</div>
```

### index.html

```
   <body ng-app="testapp">

    <div ng-controller="mycontroller">
      <button type="button" ng-click="add()">Add</button>
      <button type="button" ng-click="read()">Read Values</button>
      <br/>

      <div id="container">

      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the [ng-model directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) to bind input and textbox elements to controller variables.

Comment: Hi @georgeawg, thanks for your suggestion, the issue here is that I can add multiple directives using the Add button. I would like all those values into an array when I finally try to read all the values. How do I do this?

Comment: Avoid directly manipulating DOM in controllers. Controllers manipulate the model. Directives render DOM based on the model. Use the [ng-repeat directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to add multiple elements to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I changed your code:
working plunker [here](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/6X8Qo26vwP0jNWlD)

```
var dynamicDirective = angular.module('testapp', []);

dynamicDirective.controller('mycontroller', ['$scope', '$compile', function($scope, $compile) {

    $scope.user={
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      age: ''
    }
      $scope.add = function() {
        angular.element(document.getElementById('container'))
        .append($compile("<textbox user='user'></textbox>")($scope));
      }

      $scope.read = function(){
        console.log($scope.user);
      }


  }]);

  dynamicDirective.directive('textbox', [function() {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'dynamictextbox.html',
      scope: {
        user: '='
      },
      controller: function($scope) {

      }
    };
  }]);
```

dynamictextbox.html

```
<div>
  First name: <input type="text" ng-model='user.firstName'/> <br/>
  Last name: <input type="text" ng-model='user.lastName' /> <br/>
  Age: <input type="text" ng-model='user.age' /> <br/>
</div>
```

a user object will be log in the console.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate your help. When I add multiple directives then the same values get entered in multiple textboxes because the model is the same. How do I fix this? So when I read, I should probably get an array of user objects belonging to each directive.

Comment: You're welcome. This is another Question. Maybe instead of defining `$scope.user` you have to define a list of users and pass them like `user = users[index]` and at the end `console.log($scope.users)` . Give it a try.

Comment: @frenz  Was my answer useful? please mark it as an answer. thanks